# How to authenticate securely by session tokens and cookies? updated

Tags: php, authentication, cookies

I tried to write my own authentication method (school project), and I'm stuck.
Please advise, how to solve a secure authentication:

There is an index.php which contains everything that needs to be "protected". I will copy the relevant parts of my code here.

**updated index.php**

```
session_start();

function checkUserAuth(){
    $authStatus = false;
    if (isset($_SESSION['PHPSESSID'])){
        if ($_SESSION['PHPSESSID'] == $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']){
            $authStatus = true;
        }
    }
    return $authStatus;
}

if(!checkUserAuth()){
    include_once(dirname(__DIR__).'/admin/authentication/login.php');
    exit();
}
```

If the checkUserAuth() determines, that there is no properly authenticated user, will include the login.php and stop the rest of the script.

**updated login.php:**

```
if(array_key_exists($username, $users) && password_verify($password, $users[$username])){
    $_SESSION['PHPSESSID'] = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $_POST['user'];
```

What I imagine that might happen, is that if the login details are correct, the login.php sets a cookie, and refreshes the page. Then the index.php will detect the cookie, and skip the login part.

The login is pretty much figured out, and thanks to Juned, I think it is working now. However I don't know how secure is this?

On a scale from 1 to very, how wrong I am?

Comment: You don't manually set a session ID. Normally what most people do is have a config page that is called at the start of all your other controller pages. Within that config page, you use the start_session() function to give your user a session ID. This is sent in the form of a cookie to the user and is stored in the browser and server until they finish their session. After you've authenticated your user, you can store a variable in the $_SESSION superglobal then use an if statement in your config page to see whether that variable exists. If not, you send them to the login page.

Comment: I've updated my question with the advised code. Is this something you suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are loads of ways of doing this. The below **pseudocode** is not the most efficient but should work and I don't think what you've done above will actually work.

Does this help?

**login.php pseudocode**

```
<?php

    session_start(); // this function checks if there's a session ID already set, if not, sets one.

    if(array_key_exists($username, $users) && password_verify($password, $users[$username])){
        // do your login details checking here
            // if login details correct
                // set a flag in the $_SESSION superglobal and whatever else you want to store about the user like their username e.g.
                    $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;
                    $_SESSION["username"] = "$_POST['user']"; // better practice to fetch a clean version from your database
            //else return user to login page
    }

?>
```

**index.php pseudocode**

```
<?php

    session_start(); // this will fetch the session ID and other variables that you might have set e.g. username, logged in status

    function checkUserAuth(){
        $authStatus = false;
        if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] === true){
            $authStatus = true;
        }
        return $authStatus;
    }

    if(!checkUserAuth()){
        // redirect to login page. e.g.
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. The code I wrote did work, your looks so much nicer tho! :)